# Fax TrixBox SIP_gw

Tags: linux, asterisk, trixbox

I'm trying to recieve fax through TrixBox box, the versions of the software installed are:
OS: CentOS release 5.4 (Final)
Asterisk: 1.6.0.10-FONCORE-r40
TrixBox: v2.8.0.3

The topology is:
PSTN --> Alcatel-PBX --> Red Fone --> TrixBox --> Gw_Fax_SIP --> Fax Machine

The fax extension is:8805099 with alias 6299

I have enabled the fax detection in the inbound route with zaptel detection, the log for an incoming fax call is:

```
[May 20 13:22:04] VERBOSE[3947] logger.c:     -- Accepting call from '916695578' to '6299' on channel 0/3, span 1
[May 20 13:22:04] VERBOSE[17132] logger.c:     -- Executing [6299@from-trunk:1] Goto("DAHDI/3-1", "from-internal,8805099,1") in new stack
[May 20 13:22:04] VERBOSE[17132] logger.c:     -- Goto (from-internal,8805099,1)
[May 20 13:22:04] VERBOSE[17132] logger.c:     -- Executing [8805099@from-internal:1] Macro("DAHDI/3-1", "exten-vm,novm,8805099") in new stack
[May 20 13:22:04] VERBOSE[17132] logger.c:     -- Executing [s@macro-user-callerid:1] Set("DAHDI/3-1", "AMPUSER=916695578") in new stack
[May 20 13:22:04] VERBOSE[17132] logger.c:     -- Executing [s@macro-user-callerid:3] ExecIf("DAHDI/3-1", "1?Set(REALCALLERIDNUM=916695578)") in new stack
[May 20 13:22:04] VERBOSE[17132] logger.c:     -- Executing [s@macro-user-callerid:20] NoOp("DAHDI/3-1", "Using CallerID "" <916695578>") in new stack
[May 20 13:22:04] VERBOSE[17132] logger.c:     -- Executing [s@macro-exten-vm:4] Set("DAHDI/3-1", "EXTTOCALL=8805099") in new stack
[May 20 13:22:04] VERBOSE[17132] logger.c:     -- Executing [s@macro-exten-vm:8] Macro("DAHDI/3-1", "record-enable,8805099,IN") in new stack
[May 20 13:22:04] VERBOSE[17132] logger.c:     -- Executing [s@macro-exten-vm:9] Macro("DAHDI/3-1", "dial,"",tr,8805099") in new stack
[May 20 13:22:04] VERBOSE[17132] logger.c:  dialparties.agi: Caller ID name is 'unknown' number is '916695578'
[May 20 13:22:04] VERBOSE[17132] logger.c:     -- dialparties.agi: Added extension 8805099 to extension map
[May 20 13:22:04] VERBOSE[17132] logger.c:     -- dialparties.agi: Extension 8805099 cf is disabled
[May 20 13:22:04] VERBOSE[17132] logger.c:     -- dialparties.agi: Extension 8805099 do not disturb is disabled
[May 20 13:22:04] VERBOSE[17132] logger.c:        > dialparties.agi: extnum 8805099 has:  cw: 1; hascfb: 0 [] hascfu: 0 []
[May 20 13:22:04] VERBOSE[17132] logger.c:     -- dialparties.agi: dbset CALLTRACE/8805099 to 916695578
[May 20 13:22:04] VERBOSE[17132] logger.c:     -- dialparties.agi: Filtered ARG3: 8805099
[May 20 13:22:04] VERBOSE[17132] logger.c:     -- Executing [s@macro-dial:7] Dial("DAHDI/3-1", "SIP/8805099,"",tr") in new stack
[May 20 13:22:04] VERBOSE[17132] logger.c:     -- Called 8805099
[May 20 13:22:04] VERBOSE[17132] logger.c:     -- SIP/8805099-b74bd910 is ringing
[May 20 13:22:13] VERBOSE[17132] logger.c:     -- SIP/8805099-b74bd910 answered DAHDI/3-1
[May 20 13:23:10] VERBOSE[17132] logger.c:   == Spawn extension (from-internal, 8805099, 1) exited non-zero on 'DAHDI/3-1'
```

I have tryied NVFax detection and I have the file chan_dahdi.conf configured with faxdetect=both.

Any idea will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using alaw/ulaw i would suggest a try with T38 or vice versa.Your fax call is answered and lasts 1 minute but then it's dropped , this kind of problem can be caused by your topology, it's really difficult to handle a fax with so many steps.
You should also enable sip debug to check who is requesting the call disconnection so you'll be able to proceed with further checks in right direction.

(sometimes fax devices receive all fax correctly but then they close the call in a wrong way so the sending endpoint thinks that the call was dropped, you can try to change your fax machine)